# Get a field with jQuery when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, input-field

I have a table full of appointments. Every appointment has two buttons. One for canceling the event, one for accepting it.

I am struggling to get the `appointmentId` in the jQuery function when I click on a button. Can you please give me a hint how to do this? The `appointmentId` is in the table as a hidden input field.

```
// my html code
<tr>
  <td align="left">
     <input type="hidden" name="appointmentId" value="234">
     John Smith - 14.03.2013 at 9 o'clock
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    <input type="button" id="acceptEvent" class="acceptEvent" value="Accept">
    <input type="button" id="cancelEvent" class="cancelEvent" value="Cancel">
  </td>
</tr>

// my jQuery code
$("body").delegate('.acceptEvent', 'click', function() {  
    console.log('accept event clicked');

    // get the appointmentId here

});

$("body").delegate('.cancelEvent', 'click', function() {  
    console.log('cancel event clicked');

    // get the appointmentId here
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? As of 1.7 .delegate() has been superseded by .on().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `click` function, you have access to the button that was clicked with `this` so you can do:

```
$("body").on('click', '.cancelEvent', function() { 
     var input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="appointmentId"]').val();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use closest to grab the parent tr element, then select your hidden field.
The reason that this is the correct answer is because it takes the context of the click event with $(this).  Then it travels up the DOM tree to your root table row element and selects the child by name.  This ensures that you are always in the correct row.

EDIT:  I know you already selected an answer, but this was really bothering me that it wasn't working properly.  I had to walk down twice using .children() to get it to work though you could also use .find('input[name="appointmentId"]'). Even though you've already selected your answer, I hope this will help you.

```
$('.acceptEvent').click(function() {
    var myVal = $(this).closest('tr').children().children().val();
}); 

$('.cancelEvent').click(function() {
    var myVal = $(this).closest('tr').children().children().val();
});
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for this proposal. I tried it but myVal is `undefined`. Any idea?

Comment: @doonot  I updated my answer.  I have tested it and it works correctly.  If you still need a JSFiddle, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no other IDs or classes to key off of, you can use jQuery's [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in reference to the clicked button's parent `tr` element:

```
$('.acceptEvent').click(function() {
    // get the appointmentId here
    var appointmentId = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="appointmentId"]').val();
});
```

Comment: This is probably not a good assumption.  Most likely (since this is a table) there will be other columns with the same name

Comment: @DavidL Agreed, I updated my answer to be in reference to the clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like that :

```
$("body").on('.acceptEvent', 'click', function() {  

    var id = $('input[name="appointmentId"]').val();
    //Or search in the parent <tr> 
    var id = $(this).parent().find('input[name="appointmentId"]').val();

    console.log('accept event clicked');

    console.log('Id is ' + id);

});
```